# Convert php array and sha1 hashing function to c#

Tags: c#, php, sha1

As service provider has given me the following php code, which I need to replicate in C#

```
$aData = array('merchant_id'      => 'your merchant ID',  // 123456
               'project_id'       => 'your project ID', // 242342
               'amount'           => 'amount',    // 199 = 1,99 EUR
               'currency_code'    => 'currency code',       // EUR
               'purpose_1'        => 'subject line1',
               'merchant_key'     => 'your merchant key');  //34g1asda4524tgw
$sHash = sha1(implode('|', $aData));
```

As I only have very basic php knowledge, I would be very greatful if somebody could help me convert this into c#.

My first thought was to create a dictionary, but the pipe in the implode function is bothering me a bit. So what kind of array/list should I be using?

Then how would I "implode" the list?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks goes to @andreas and @Mchl!
The following code returns a hash of 65f23ce1507167668691445bd35451e4c6b0572b.

```
        //test
        string merchantId = "your merchant ID";
        string projectId = "your project ID";
        string amount = "amount";
        string currency = "currency code";
        string invoiceId = "subject line1";
        string merchantKey = "your merchant key";

        string imploded = merchantId + "|" + projectId + "|" + amount + "|" + currency + "|" + invoiceId + "|"+merchantKey;
        byte[] arrayData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(imploded);
        byte[] hash = SHA1.ComputeHash(arrayData);
        //return hash.ToString();
        string result = null;
        string temp = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            temp = Convert.ToString(hash[i], 16);
            if (temp.Length == 1)
                temp = "0" + temp;
            result += temp;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically calling sha1 method on the concatenated array values | separated:

`sha1("123456|242342|199|EUR|subject1|34g1asda4524tgw");`

I'm no C# expert, but I guess having to do that in C# is trivial :)

---

Here are some reference results for you:

```
>> $aData = array('merchant_id'      => 'your merchant ID',  // 123456
..                'project_id'       => 'your project ID', // 242342
..                'amount'           => 'amount',    // 199 = 1,99 EUR
..                'currency_code'    => 'currency code',       // EUR
..                'purpose_1'        => 'subject line1',
..                'merchant_key'     => 'your merchant key');  //34g1asda4524tgw

>> $aData;
array (
  'merchant_id' => 'your merchant ID',
  'project_id' => 'your project ID',
  'amount' => 'amount',
  'currency_code' => 'currency code',
  'purpose_1' => 'subject line1',
  'merchant_key' => 'your merchant key',
)

>> implode('|',$aData);
'your merchant ID|your project ID|amount|currency code|subject line1|your merchant key'

>> sha1(implode('|',$aData));
'65f23ce1507167668691445bd35451e4c6b0572b'
```

Comment: Not a good idea btw (the code provided in question), since you need to make sure array's keys are in specific order (and it's not alphabetic)

Comment: I agree, it would be better if the array keys are integer since the code doesn't really care about the keys anyway, but yeah that's just me giving the OP idea :)

Comment: thanks! I'll post my working c# code when I've got it working! right now I can't get my hash result and that of the example to match..

Comment: @AyKarsi: Just a sanity check: `sha1('0') ='b6589fc6ab0dc82cf12099d1c2d40ab994e8410c'` here. Check if you get same result ;)

Answer (score 0):

The implode requires some form of ordered list. Thus `Dictionary<K,V>` is not the right choice. I'd go with `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>`.

You need to add the pairs in the same order as php enumerates them. No idea if that's addition order or undefined,...

The next problem is how php treats key-value pairs in this context. The documentation for `implode` doesn't state that. My example just uses the value in the pair.

```
string joinedString=string.Join("|", list.Value);
```

Next you need to convert the string to a byte array. For this you need to choose an encoding that matches the encoding php uses, but no idea which that is. For example with UTF-8:

```
string joinedBytes=Utf8Encoding.GetBytes(joinedString);
```